# Skydrive sync in portable class library / mvvmcross

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, mvvmcross, portable-class-library, live-sdk

I have portable library (mvvmcross) solution and in Core project I have Live SDK method:

```
Client.DownloadCompleted += delegate(object o, LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {...}

Client.DownloadAsync(SKYDRIVE_PATH + USER_DEFINED_FILE);
```

There is problem with LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs:

Error   1   The type 'System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

Where I find this System assembly? I tried to add this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll"
```

but it is impossible to add system assembly.

Comment: But *Live SDK* does not provide a PCL library, right? You can't reference, say, a pure .NET Framework library from a PCL. However, there seems to be some kind of PCL helper library for *Live SDK* on *NuGet*, please read more [here](http://metronuggets.com/2013/06/25/belatedly-introducing-livesdkhelper/).

Comment: Live SDK doesn't work in mvvmcross (only WinRT+Wp), so I have rather solved it in native platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly if an API/library isn't available portably, then you won't be able to force it to be available by adding references to different System.dll assemblies.

Whenever APIs aren't available portably, I recommend either:

- wrapping them behind interfaces and injecting them into the portable code from the native platforms. There are some examples of this in N=31 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/
- choose to put your code into non-portable libraries with code shared through file linking rather than through PCLs

Daniel Plaisted has more ideas on this at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx